# When my Symfony2 app is using cache, when not? How do I know?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, memcached, apc

Having this entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="nomencladores.pais", schema="nomencladores")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\PaisRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"nombre"}, message="El pais ya existe en nuestra base de datos")
 */
class Pais
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait;
    use NamedEntityTrait;
    use ActiveEntityTrait;
}
```

And this Repository:

```
class PaisRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getPaises()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('pais');
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $query->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'paises_cache');

        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

And doing this call on my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/paises", name="paises")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function getPaisAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Pais')->getPaises();

    $response['message'] = "";
    $response['entities'] = [];

    if (!$entities) {
        $response['message'] = "No se encontraron países";
    }

    foreach ($entities as $pais) {
        $paises = array();
        $paises['id'] = $pais->getId();
        $paises['text'] = $pais->getNombre();
        $response['entities'][] = $paises;
    }

    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

And having this at `config_prod.yml` file:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc
```

How do I know if my app is using cache results or is doing a DB query all the time? I'm seeing into Symfony2 toolbar (because I'm performing test at dev environment) and all the time I'm seeing the query for `paises` table which makes me think no cache is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have to tell Doctrine when to use the configured caching driver, like so:

```
public function getSomeEntities()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

    $qb
        ->where('a.title = "test article"')
        ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ;

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    $query->useResultCache(true, 60, 'uniqueCacheId');

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

You can also specify the use of query caching:

```
$query->useQueryCache(true);
```

You can see in the [Doctrine\ORM\Query class documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/class-Doctrine.ORM.Query.html) that the `useQueryCache` function accepts a single boolean parameter and the `useResultCache` has the following parameters:

`useResultCache( boolean $bool, integer $timeToLive = null, string $resultCacheId = null )`